# Como puedo lograr afichar el resultado de una lista?

Tags: c#, linq, lista

Tengo un programa el cual me devuelve `system.collections.generic.list 1 system.object`

He tratado varias veces que me devuelva el valor real de este parametro y de cambiarlo segun lo que he encontrado en google pero no me resulta.

Lo que estoy intentando de hacer es usar Linq para poder obtener el valor de una lista:

```
Response[] resp = db.GetResponse();

for (int i = 0; i < resp.Length; ++i)
{
    int userIDindex = -1;
    int fnIndex = -1;
    int lnIndex = -1;

    if (resp.Length > 0)
    {
        // the first record contains the names of the fields
        for (int j = 0; j < resp[i].List.Length; j++)
        {
            if (resp[i].List[j].ToString() == "Q9Row1")
                userIDindex = j;
            else if (resp[0].List[j].ToString() == "SubjectID")
                lnIndex = j;

        }

         if (userIDindex >= 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < resp.Length; k++)
            {
                var userData = resp[k].List;

                List<string> toEmailAdresses = new List<string>();
                string fromEmailAddress = "";
                string bodyMessage = "";

                List<string> projectId = new List<string>();

                int count = xml.GetElementsByTagName("toEmailAdresses").Count;

                for (int t = 0; t < count; ++t)
                {
                    {
                        while ((userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("3", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                        userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("4", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))) //&&
                        {    
                            if (userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("3", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                            userData[userIDindex].ToString().Equals("4", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                toEmailAdresses.Add(xml.GetElementsByTagName("toEmailAdresses")[t].InnerText);
                                bodyMessage = xml.GetElementsByTagName("bodyMessage").ToString();
                                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("test@test.org", toEmailAdresses[t].ToString());
                                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                                client.Port = 25;
                                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                                client.Host = "localhost"; //here goes the smpt connection
                                mail.Subject = "Testing email";     
                                mail.Body = bodyMessage[t] + "___" + userData[lnIndex].ToString().Select(r => r.ToString() == "SubjectID").ToList();
                                client.Send(mail);               
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que obtengo de la lista de resp:

```
<Response>
    <List>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q9Row1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q9Comment1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q10Row1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q10Comment1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Q11Row1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SubjectID</anyType>

    </List>
</Response>
<Response>
    <List>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">2</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">1</anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">user1</anyType>
    </List>
</Response>
```

Lo que busco cual es el valor de SubjectID de la lista.

Como puedo lograr esto?

Gracias de ante mano

Comment: pero deberias mandar ese valor, no subjetId.

Comment: Que es `resp`? Que es `List`?

Comment: Si ya estoy mandando ese valor anteriormente en el codigo, voy a editar la pregunta para mostrar el codigo donde y como lo estoy mandando

Comment: ya edite la pregunta agregando el codigo entero, gracias

Comment: podrías describir a modo de enunciado qué es lo que deseas lograr? Según lo que puedo compilar con la vista, veo varios puntos de posible ruptura: valida que los datos que vayas a leer sean diferentes de null, esta línea  var userData = resp[k].List; te va a marcar error, tienes un array de elementos y dentro tienes una lista? No sería mejor que lo definas sin la lista? El envío de correos genéralo en otro método, así mantendrás una mayor separación de responsabilidades y te será más sencillo realizar una depuración en caso de errores.

Comment: Finalmente en esta línea: userData[lnIndex], por ningún lado veo la variable lnIndex que retorne la posición del elemento, tienes la certeza que va un .ToString() antes del .Select(r => r.ToString() == "SubjectID") ? y para que termines asignando .ToList() a la línea mail.Body = bodyMessage[t] + "___" ... ?

Comment: hola, cuando no puse ToString() antes del select me arojo una advertencia de hacer un Cast de string antes del ==. Tienes razon voy a poner en un metodo aparte el envio de correos electronicos. Y si me devuelve bien la posicion de la lista cuando hago el begugger. Lo que quiero hacer que en la posicion de esa lista esta justamente el SubjectID que deseo mostrar

Comment: Todavía no me queda claro qué tipo de objeto contiene `resp[i].List`. O en otras palabras, en la sentencia `var userData = resp[k].List;`, ¿cual es el tipo de `userData`?

Comment: lo que obtiene resp[i].List es el resultado completo de la lista, el cual solo lo uso para mostrar en  textBox1.Text += Form1.arrayToString(resp[k].List);
Ya agregue la estructura de la lista en la pregunta